# Wordpress user query with meta vaue orderby

Tags: php, wordpress

i have users with 2 custom meta fields. Vip (0 or 1) and likes (numeric)
I need to query users with orderby them by Vip and likes, so i need that first was vip users, than users with max likes. 
I have such code

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',                            

    'vip_clause' => array( 
        'key'=> 'vip',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'   ,       
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'  ,                                                                    
    ),

    'like_clause' =>  array( 
        'key'=> 'al_likes',
         'type' => 'NUMERIC',
         'compare' => 'EXISTS'   ,                                        
    ),
    array( 
        'key'=> 'vip',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'   ,
    ), 
    array( 
        'key'=> 'al_likes',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'   ,                                  
    ),
);

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,                  
    'orderby'  => array(    
    'like_clause' => 'DESC',    
    'vip_clause' => 'DESC'
   )    
); 

$users =  new WP_User_Query ( $args );
```

As a result i get lists of users which are ordered by Vip (them first) but not by likes too. How can i fix it? Thank you

Comment: Your code example seems to contain error: there is no closing parenthesis for `'orderby'  => array(`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "orderby" parameter of WP_User_Query doesn't support array value.  I guess you took the sample from WP_QUERY, which is for POST data.
Try using simple, comma separated string, instead of array. WP_USER_QUERY can recognize it.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,  
     'order'      => 'DESC,DESC',
     'orderby'    => 'like_clause,vip_clause',                                   
);
```

Comment: are you sure al_likes is correct name? may be it is all_likes?

Comment: yes, it is correct, but i can`t now to order with only    like_clause

Comment: i just remembered that wp_user_query didn't support multicolumn orderby. and then googled and found this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169361/56767   So you need custom solution for this. f.e. ordering it with php array sort, it would not be difficult.

Comment: i thought about custom php array sort, but i also have pagination here

Comment: Yeah, you need another meta field which has merged values of vip+likes. You can create and synch it in places where original ones are changed. Then simple orderby meta_value_num would be enough. Php sorting will not be needed.  I know it is not the best way, but it will 100% meet your needs and solve the problem.